# Why a requests.get() does not work within a loop, but works outside?

Tags: python, xml, python-requests

I got this function to extract data from a XML (internal network, I can't provide the URL for security reasons):

```
def crawl_and_get_data(url, keys, param1, param2, param3):

    r = requests.get(url, auth = HTTPDigestAuth(keys[0], keys[1]))

    xml_url = 'http://www.sitetogetdata.com/xml/?param1=' + param1 + '&param2=' + param2 + '&param3=' + param3

    res = requests.get(xml_url, auth = HTTPDigestAuth(keys[0], keys[1]))
    xml = res.text

    return xml
```

I want this function to work within a loop that takes `param1`, `param2` and `param3`.

```
frames = []

for i in range(len(table_with_params)):

    try:

        param1 = int(table_with_params.loc[i, 'param1'])
        param2 = int(table_with_params.loc[i, 'param2'])
        param3 = int(table_with_params.loc[i, 'param3'])

        data = crawl_and_get_data(url, keys, param1, param2, param3)
        frames.append(data)

    except TypeError:
        print('Whoops, something is wrong with this request.')
        continue
```

For the majority of cases it works, but for some specific cases it doesn't. After the execution, I try to get the data again but outside the loop, and it works.

```
data = crawl_and_get_data(url, keys, problematic_param1, problematic_param2, problematic_param3)
# it works!
```

Any hints on it? Thanks in advance.

---

EDIT: Skipping the exception treatment, the error returned is:

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

This error is not thrown when the function runs out of the loop.

Comment: What error do you have?

Comment: can you share code and error

Comment: @Alderven, it is a TypeError, coming from the int casting in the params. Piyush, code is already shared.

Comment: pls post your error code completly at the op.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are so many reasons an HTTP request could fail that it's a miracle they sometimes succeed, so you'd better be prepared for a failed request. This being said, your problem might actually be totally elsewhere and your (rather bad) exception handling is preventing you from getting any hint.

Your first problem here is that your try block is way too large, you want to restrict a try block to the strict necessary. The second problem is that you totally ignore the actual exception and just print a perfectly useless message.

Currently, you have mainly three distinct parts in your try block: preparing your request's argument, doing the request itself (actually 2 requests), and doing something with the result. Each of those parts can raise it's own specific exceptions, so a proper exception handling scheme would be to have each part in a distinct try block (or at least outside the other try blocks if you don't expect anything special - the  "do something with the result" part being just `frames.append(data)`, it doesn't really warrant a try/except block). IOW, you want something like this:

```
try:

    param1 = int(table_with_params.loc[i, 'param1'])
    param2 = int(table_with_params.loc[i, 'param2'])
    param3 = int(table_with_params.loc[i, 'param3'])

except TypeError as e:
    print("invalid source value at row {} : {}".format(i, e))
    continue


try:
    data = crawl_and_get_data(url, keys, param1, param2, param3)
```

you should NOT get any TypeError here - Theoretically, that is, see lower for what might be your real issue

```
 except RequestError as e:
    print("Failed request for row {} : {}".format(i, e))
    continue

frames.append(data)
```

Note that using the `logging` module would be better, specially since it knows how to properly log the full error traceback (which most often contains very valuable debugging informations).

Also note that:

```
def crawl_and_get_data(url, keys, param1, param2, param3):

    r = requests.get(url, auth = HTTPDigestAuth(keys[0], keys[1]))
```

if the goal is to log in and the url is constant in the outer (calling) loop, you may want to [have a look at requests sessions instead](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects), this could halves the number of queries. Else it's a bit of a waste of time, bandwidth and cpu cycles for you AND the target server. Be kind to the server's owner please.

```
    xml_url = 'http://www.sitetogetdata.com/xml/?param1=' + param1 + '&param2=' + param2 + '&param3=' + param3    
    res = requests.get(xml_url, auth = HTTPDigestAuth(keys[0], keys[1]))
```

And now here is a source for a `TypeError` (assuming what you posted is your real code or similar enough): you explicitely convert your params values to `int` in the caller code, and now try to concatenate those ints with strings. This does not work and raises a `TypeError` indeed (for very good reasons - languages that silently cast incompatible types are broken by design).

As a general rule, you should better using string formatting than string concatenation for those kind of operations, ie:

```
xml_url = '...?param1={}&param2={}&param3={}'.format(param1, param2, param3)
```

which is not only more readable, but will call `str()` (or the appriate format function depending on format specifier), avoiding a `TypeError`.

BUT there are other pitfalls with HTTP querystrings, and [`python-requests` already knows how to properly create a valid querystring from a dict](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls), so you should actually use:

```
   res = requests.get(url, params={"param1": param1, "param2": param2, "param3": param3}, ....)
```

Comment: Bruno, thanks for your feedback. About the second problem specifically, I just changed the message to post in here, but in fact the original is 'There is a type issue with param1, param2 and param3'. About the try blocks, nice feedback as well. I edited the question and added the error, which now seems to me to be a casting issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error is not coming from crawling.. It is in the the following lines:

`param1 = int(table_with_params.loc[i, 'param1'])
param2 = int(table_with_params.loc[i, 'param2'])
param3 = int(table_with_params.loc[i, 'param3'])`

One of these lines is returning a pandas Series object which can't be cast to int. 
Pardon my formatting, as I am new to stackoverflow and don't know how to format the code correctly.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you are right. I would accept your answer but bruno's answer is more complete and mentions the casting too. Don't worry about formatting, I'm new to SO as well. :)